# How to fetch email id from JSON file in firebase using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[JSON Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7yZA.png)I want to query like: If I give email, then I have to get the ID. At the moment I can fetch email or ID but I need solution for below example.

For example 
1) if I give `sandeep@gmail.com` then I need it's ID as `123`.

How can I achieve this in swift?

This is my `JSON` file:

```
{
   "ID": 123,
   "Membership": 1234,
   "title": "Mr.",
   "firstname": "kumar",
   "lastname": "sandeep",
   "email": "sandeep@gmail.com",
   "membrshipstatus": "Active",
   "volunteer": "Yes",
   "creationDate": "2016-12-27 "
 },

{
   "ID": 452,
   "Membership": 4531,
   "title": "Mr.",
   "firstname": "kumar",
   "lastname": "sandeep",
   "email": "harry@gmail.com",
   "membrshipstatus": "Active",
   "volunteer": "Yes",
   "creationDate": "2016-11-17 "
 },
```

This is my `Swift` code:

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseAuth

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var emailofUser: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var passwordofUser: UITextField!
        var ref:FIRDatabaseReference! //created a variable ref of type firebase database reference
        var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle? //to handle to database listener like to stop or start it


        var postdata = [String]?()
        var postall = [[String:String]]()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //set firebase reference
            ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("1").child("email").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            let emailid = snapshot.value as? String

            print(emailid)
        })

ref.child("1").child("ID").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot1 in

            let userID = snapshot1.value as? Int

            print(userID)
        })

            ref.queryOrderedByValue().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot2 in
                if let parentname = snapshot2.value as? Int {
                    print("The \(snapshot2.key) dinosaur's score is \(parentname)")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Swift Code related to this JSON image:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



            //set firebase reference
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let userRef = ref.child("1")

        //let queryRef = userRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("mr.stefankirsch@gmx.com")


        userRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("mr.stefankirsch@gmx.com").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children{

            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot

                let userDict = snap.value as! [String:Any]

                let userId = userDict["ID"]
                let lastname = userDict["lastname"]
                print("\(userId!)  \(lastname!)")


            }
                    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON response with Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939143/parse-json-response-with-swift-3)

Comment: Sorry my question is different. For example 1) if I give sandeep@gmail.com then I need it's ID as 123.

How can I achieve this in swift?

Comment: This is a basic query in Firebase. Please see my answer and also read up on [Working with Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) in particular the Sorting and Filtering data section.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the uid of the user to store data in the users node in general. Assuming your users node is called /users... like this

```
users
  uid_0
   "ID": 123,
   "Membership": 1234,
   "title": "Mr.",
   "firstname": "kumar",
   "lastname": "sandeep",
   "email": "sandeep@gmail.com"
  uid_1
   "ID": 452,
   "Membership": 4531,
   "title": "Mr.",
   "firstname": "kumar",
   "lastname": "sandeep"
   "email": "harry@gmail.com"
```

here's the query to get the data you are asking about

```
let usersRef = ref.child("users")
let queryRef = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
                       .queryEqual(toValue: "sandeep@gmail.com")
queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

     for child in snapshot.children {
          let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
          let userDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
          let userId = userDict["ID"]
          let lastname = userDict["lastname"]
          print("\(userId!)  \(lastname!)")
      }
})
```

and the result prints:

```
123  sandeep
```

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried this code, but its not printing anything. please help.

Comment: @SandeepKumat I copy and pasted that code from a working project. Make sure your Firebase structure matches what's in the answer. You didn't include a full snippet of your JSON structure in the original question so I had to assume a structure.

Comment: Hi Jay,I just added JSON image and code according to that JSON structure. Please verify my code. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @SandeepKumat this is probably the issue *let userRef = ref.child("1")* but the json structure is still incomplete without a parent node.